# send Image byte data in json request in android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to send image byte data in Http Post in android and iPhone.

Let me know hoe to send Image data in JSON Like below JSON String

```
 {
 "Request": {
    "data": {
    "Key": "keydata",
    "info": {},
    "param": {
        "title": "Testingpostmultipartimageupload",
        "photo": **"IMAGE BYTE DATA"**,
        "photoFilename": "Test.png"
    }
},
"info": {}
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ba); 
    byte[] bmpbyte_sign = ba.toByteArray();
```

pass bmpbyte_sign.
Hope will help u...

Comment: thn i think u can also pass the base64 of that image

Comment: I have did but no luck, I want exact code to send this kind of data in JSON basic thing to send image data I have did that

Answer (score 0):

Dude just convert the image into the bytes then decode with this data with base64 string and pass that string in the json. BTW I'm from iPhone

Comment: I have did but no luck, I want exact code to send this kind of data in JSON basic thing to send image data I have did that